# Can't run client-server socket on port 5000

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I have a school assignment to create a server client socket and run it specifically on port 5000. When I do, I get the error "OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use". I ran sudo lsof -i:5000 in my terminal, and my command center is running on port 5000. I tried to kill it, but it automatically rejuvenates. What can I do to get around this? My project worked when I ran it on port 6000, but I specifically have to use port 5000. Here is my code.

Server.py

```
import socket


# Function to reverse the message received from the client
def reverse_message(data):
    return data[::-1]


# Function to run the server and receive message from client
def run_server():
    port = 5000
    # Creating a TCP socket for the server
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Binding the server socket to the specified port
    server_socket.bind(('', port))
    # Listening for incoming connections
    server_socket.listen(1)

    while True:
        # Accepting a connection from the client
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

        # Receiving data from the client
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        # Checking if the received message is "end"
        if data == "end":
            client_socket.send(reverse_message(data).encode())
            break
        else:
            # Sending the reversed message to the client
            client_socket.send(reverse_message(data).encode())

    # Closing the server socket
    server_socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

Client.py

```
import socket


# Function to run the client and send messages to the server
def run_client():
    name = 'servername'
    port = 5000
    # Creating a TCP socket for the client
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Connecting to the server at the specified IP and port
    client_socket.connect((name, port))

    while True:
        # Reading input message from the user
        message = input("Enter message (enter 'end' to terminate): ")
        # Sending the message to the server
        client_socket.send(message.encode())

        # Receiving the response from the server
        response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        # Checking if the received message is "dne"
        if response == "dne":
            print(response)
            break
        else:
            # Printing the received message
            print("Received response:", response)

    # Closing the client socket
    print("Closing client socket")
    client_socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_client()
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

port 5000 is commonly used to serve local development servers.

By running lsof -i :5000, you can see the port was named ControlCenter, which is a native macOS application. If this happens to you, even if you use  kill the application, it will restart itself.

The process running on this port turns out to be an AirPlay server. You can deactivate it in System Preferences › Sharing and uncheck AirPlay Receiver to release port 5000. right after you will be able to use the port!
cheers,